# sql redundancy table column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgresql and I have a form which has duplication of block data, this is how the form look like

```
f_name
l_name
f_name_2
l_name_2
f_name_3
l_name_3
```

This is how the UI look like. So how do I should design my table? should I create one table which has the column of above field? or I should have a table with only 2 columns? and create another table to hold the PK?

Comment: it really depends on your usage. Simply add them all the one table with a PK. They all look related to each other so i would see no need to split them out.

Comment: I don't get it, when should I go with 1 or 2 tables?

Comment: On the face of it a table would hold similar information or information from a common source. These all look the same, so one column for each with a PK ?